# Cmd crashes with exit code 1 after uninstalling anaconda

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, crash, anaconda, exit-code

On Win10 Pro, `Cmd` crashes with `exit code 1` after uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda; since then, I've been unable to access Command Prompt.

- As soon as I open `cmd`, it closes, and opening within VSCode returns error:

  ```powershell
  Cmd has exited with error code 1
  ```
- If I execute `cmd` in PowerShell, it exits immediately without providing an error message, but if I execute `cmd /d` it works
- The Anaconda Prompt is also not starting up, but as soon as I open PowerShell, it says `(conda)`, so I think it works there

According to [this](https://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/actions/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/) website, `ErrorCode 1` indicates:

> Incorrect function. 
> Indicates that Action has attempted to execute non-recognized command in Windows command prompt `cmd.exe`

I've tried the following, with none working:

- Removed Anaconda from `PATH`
- A Registry fix for startup commands for `cmd`, but the Registry entry was missing in my case *(maybe this could be the issue?)*
- ```powershell
  Sfc /ScanNow
  ```
- ```powershell
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth
  ```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 6):

With the help of @Mofi in a StackOverflow question, executing the following in PowerShell fixes it:

```
Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```

Comment: Oh wow, this saved my butt after months of pain. Thank you!!!!